# How to reuse computation graph for different inputs?

Tags: python, theano

I have my main flow of computation set up that I can train using

```
train = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=[cost], updates=updates)
```

Similarly, I have a function for predictions

```
predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=[output])
```

Both of these functions accept the input `x` and send it through the same computation graph.

I would now like to modify things so that when training, I can train using a noisy input, so I have something like

```
input = get_corrupted_input(self.theano_rng, x, 0.5)
```

at the beginning of the computations.

But this will also affect my `predict` function, since its input will get corrupted as well. How can I reuse the same code for `train` and `predict`, but only provide the former with the noisy input?

Answer (score 1):

You can organise your code like this:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams


def get_cost(x, y):
    return tt.mean(tt.sum(tt.sqr(x - y), axis=1))


def get_output(x, w, b_h, b_y):
    h = tt.tanh(tt.dot(x, w) + b_h)
    y = tt.dot(h, w.T) + b_y
    return y


def corrupt_input(x, corruption_level):
    rng = tt.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams()
    return rng.binomial(size=x.shape, n=1, p=1 - corruption_level,
                        dtype=theano.config.floatX) * x


def compile(input_size, hidden_size, corruption_level, learning_rate):
    x = tt.matrix()
    w = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(input_size,
                      hidden_size).astype(theano.config.floatX))
    b_h = theano.shared(numpy.zeros(hidden_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    b_y = theano.shared(numpy.zeros(input_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    cost = get_cost(x, get_output(corrupt_input(x, corruption_level), w, b_h, b_y))
    updates = [(p, p - learning_rate * tt.grad(cost, p)) for p in (w, b_h, b_y)]
    train = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=cost, updates=updates)
    predict = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=get_output(x, w, b_h, b_y))
    return train, predict


def main():
    train, predict = compile(input_size=3, hidden_size=2,
                             corruption_level=0.2, learning_rate=0.01)


main()
```

Note that `get_output` is called twice. For the `train` function it is provided with the corrupted input but for the `predict` function it is provided with the clean input. `get_output` needs to contain "the same computation graph" that you talk of. I've just put a tiny autoencoder in there but you can put whatever you want in there.

Assuming the corrupted input has the same shape as the input, the `get_output` function won't care whether its input is `x` or the corrupted version of `x`. So `get_output` can be shared but need not contain the corruption code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. How does the function `get_output()` work? Don't `train` and `predict` still have the same inputs in your code?

Comment: @Fequish I've updated my answer with a fuller explanation.