# How to reuse a computation graph with different inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I'd like to use the same computation graph with different inputs in TensorFlow. Unfortunately, I didn't write the model function and I would like to avoid modifying it if at all possible.

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # some code here
    return loss, train_op
```

I'm writing a federated learning algorithm and I want to train the same model on *n* different datasets, without having *n* clients, so I planned on using a single computation graph and different inputs.

I planned on doing this like so:

```py
with tf.variable_scope("client", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    for _ in range(num_of_clients):
        features, labels = input_fn()
        client_model = model_fn(features, labels, "train")
```

I had hoped that client_model would reuse all of the shared variables.

- I can confirm that it doesn't with `tf.global_variables()`.
- I also know that if `model_fn()` used `tf.get_variable()`, this would work, but it doesn't.

How would I do this in TensorFlow **without** modifying the `model_fn` (otherwise I would just use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858990/how-to-reuse-computation-graph-for-different-inputs))?